# Stuck implementing a nested data filtering loop, possibly a more elegant way of doing this?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's the data. What I want to do is inject all this data into one variable that contains all the categories and all the books belonging to those categories:

```
var categories = [

    // ...

    {
        "_id" : "5436b12b456f61180f815c06",
        "name" : "Horror"
    },

    {
        "_id" : "5436b43f18bbc8a8073e786e",
        "name" : "Action"
    }

    // ...

];

var books = [

    // ...

    {
        "_id" : "5436b43f18bbc8a8073e786d",
        "title" : "The Bourne Legacy",
        "category" : "5436b43f18bbc8a8073e786e"
    },

    {
        "_id" : "5436b5c9de9884e010d5ef24",
        "title" : "Digital Fortress",
        "category" : "5436b50dc6faf3d41071a669"
    }

    // ...

];
```

And this is a mockup of how I'd like the data to look like after filtering:

```
categories_titles = [
    {
        categoryName: 'Category One',
        categoryTitles: [
          {title: 'Book 1'},
          {title: 'Book 2'},
          // ...
        ]
    },

    {
        categoryName: 'Category Two',
        categoryTitles: [
          {title: 'Book 3'},
          {title: 'Book 4'},
          // ...
        ]
    }
];
```

And this is how I'm trying to solve the problem:

```
categories_titles= [];

for (var category in categories) {
    for (var book in books) {
        if (books[book].category == categories[category]._id) {
            categories_titles.push(
                {
                    name: categories[category].name,
                    titles: [
                        {title: books[book].title}
                    ]
                }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

This method works only partially; all the categories are being listed but some are being repeated, and some titles are missing or otherwise not where they're supposed to be.

Also, accessing items, something like: `categories_titles[0].titles[0].title` is quite a monstrosity and I have a feeling that this could be solved more elegantly.

Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a much better way to do this.  I'm going to rearrange your data structure.  The filter to go from my data structure to yours is a linear time algorithm, though I don't see why you'd want to.  But if you must, the translation is linear time.

```
result = {};

for (var category in categories) {
    result[category._id] = {name : category.name, books: []};
}

for (var book in books) {
    //Probably also want some safety logic for if result[book.category] is undefined...

    addBook(result[book.category].books, book); //you already know how to add your book info, so I won't duplicate that logic.
}
```

Afterwards you can either return result, or do logic to change result into your mocked up data structure.  But creating this preliminary structure will save you computation time, because dictionary accesses are MUCH faster than iterating over your arrays multiple times.

If b = number of books and c = number of categories.

Complexity Your algorithm: O(b * c)

Complexity My algorithm: O(b + c)

Complexity My algorithm with translation to your data structure O(2 * (b + c)) though the memory complexity goes up.  A good tradeoff for this problem, in my opinion.  O(b*c) is not very good.

Comment: Quite insightful. However, this data is being pulled from a MongoDB database by a model and if filtering appears to be this complex, perhaps I got my data modeling all wrong, which is clearly the case since I set up the database collections in a hurry (I'm learning/experimenting with this stuff). The takeaway here being that in future, I should model my data while considering the type of queries that will be performed on them.

Comment: It looks to me like you're data models are thinking in terms of SQL... which is great for SQL.  But they don't often translate to mongodb well.  Or at least, not while leaving you efficient ways of manipulating the data.  But I'm not a mongodb expert in any sense of the term.